# Связывание Entity Framework Core SqLite с WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, entity-framework, .net-core

Как связать `WPF` с `EF Core Sqlite` и что прописывать в `app.config`? Если нельзя связать `.net core` с `.net framework`, то какие ещё есть варианты решения проблемы (кроме использования старых EF)?

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Filename=Mobile.db");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
   var connectionStringBuilder = new SqliteConnectionStringBuilder { DataSource = “Mobile.db” };
   var connectionString = connectionStringBuilder.ToString();
   var connection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString);
   optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(connection);
}
```

А по конкретнее можете читать [здесь](http://learn.foyzulkarim.com/dot-net-desktop-application-wpf-wf-with-sqlite-database-using-entity-framework-core-part-1/)

Для поддержки `SQLite` необходимо изменить конфигурацию проекта, которая располагается в файле `App.config`. После добавления пакетов данный файл также автоматически изменяется. Однако все же нам необходимо внести в него некоторые изменения.Нужно изменить его следующим образом:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <configSections>
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
 </configSections>
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\mobiles.db" providerName="System.Data.SQLite" />
 </connectionStrings>
<startup>
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6" />
</startup><entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="v11.0" />
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite"  type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6"/>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
</providers>
</entityFramework><system.data>
<DbProviderFactories>
  <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
<add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
</DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
</configuration>
```

Здесь определена строка подключения

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\Mobile.db" providerName="System.Data.SQLite" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Так как созданный вами файл базы данных называется Mobile (к которому 
`DB Browser for SQLite` по умолчанию добавляет расширение db),то в качестве источника данных здесь указан именно `"Mobile.db"`.

Другой важный момент - **установка в узле  провайдера**, который будет использоваться для подключения

```
<provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite"  type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6"/>
```

Для работы с `SQLite` вам нужно установить специальный инструмент [DB Browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org/)

Comment: "Для работы с SQLite вам нужно установить специальный инструмент " зачем? (имею ввиду что не `нужно`, а `можно` или `удобно`) - то есть рекомендация, а не требование.

Comment: @FoggyFinder общая логика была построена на создании БД  с помощю `Code First`.В отличие от работы с `MS SQL Server` по отношению к `SQLite EF 6` не поддерживает автоматическое создание БД и ее таблиц через `Code First`.В этом случае нам самим надо создавать БД и ее таблицы и по этому было написано нужно,но можем и поменять на `можно` или `удобно` .Думаю из этого логика не пострадает ;)

Comment: @VardanVardanyan почему вы решили, что EF Core не может создать SQLite БД в случае работы `Code First`? Все прекрасно работает. И зачем в конфиг пихать ссылки на `System.Data.SQLite.EF6` ?